# lua:attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Now I've hit a roadblock getting this error on and on for the following code

> box.lua:31: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

I tried to correct this error, but failed.

Below is all the complete code

```
    function ChatSystem(event, player, msg, Type, lang)
        local Guid = player:GetGUIDLow()
        if flag[Guid] ~= 0 then
            local daan = quiz["box"][flag[Guid]][2];
            local t = msg;
            if (t+1 == daan+1) then
                player:SendBroadcastMessage("[Notice]correct")
                SetPlayerFlag(player, 0)
                SetPlayererror(player, 0)
            else
                cuowu[Guid] = error[Guid] + 1;
                if cuowu[Guid] >= quiz["frequency"] then
                    SetPlayererror(player, 0)
                    Kick( player )
                else
                    player:SendBroadcastMessage("[Notice]  error"..cuowu[Guid].."   "..quiz["box"][flag[Guid]][1].."");
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    
    function Start (event, player, item, count)
        local datigailv = math.random(1, 100)
        if (datigailv <= quiz["Chance"])then
            local select = math.random(1, 5)
            local Guid = player:GetGUIDLow()
            SetPlayerFlag(player, select)
            SetPlayererror(player, 0)
            player:SendBroadcastMessage("[Notice]answer my question:"..quiz["box"][flag[Guid]][1].."");
        end
    end
    
    RegisterPlayerEvent(32, Start) 
    RegisterPlayerEvent(18, ChatSystem);
```

Comment: Do you have anything right after this error?

Comment: either `quiz["box"]` or `quiz["box"][flag[Guid]]` is nil

Comment: By the way, the low part of a GUID is not a GUID. You might even have two players with the same low part.

Comment: Logical error at: `if flag[Guid] ~= 0 then`. If `flag[Guid]` is `nil` then it is allways true, change it to: `if (flag[Guid] or 0) ~= 0`

Comment: One more logical error at: `if (t+1 == daan+1) then`. If `t` value is non numerical string or empty string then it will throw an error. Change to:`if tonumber(t) == daan then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As array in array error is hard to track, if it is possible, try to avoid it or add some asserts like `assert(quiz["box"][flag[Guid]])` to check if you have such array value.

In lua you can delete value with `flag[Guid] = nil` instead of `flag[Guid] = 0`.

My version without arrays and dynamic question generation:

```lua
local quiz = {
  chance = 2,
  frequency = 3
}

local quiz_flags = {}

function ChatSystem(event, player, msg, Type, lang)
  local quiz_info = quiz_flags[player:GetGUIDLow()]
  if quiz_info then
    if tonumber(msg) == quiz_info.answer then
      player:SendBroadcastMessage('[Notice] correct')
      quiz_flags[player:GetGUIDLow()] = nil -- remove flag info
    elseif quiz_info.count >= quiz.frequency then
      quiz_flags[player:GetGUIDLow()] = nil -- remove flag info
      Kick(player)
    else
      player:SendBroadcastMessage('[Notice] error '..quiz_info.count..',   '..quiz_info.question..'=?')
      quiz_info.count = quiz_info.count + 1
    end
  end
end
    
function Start(event, player, item, count)
  if math.random(1, 100) <= quiz.chance then
    -- generate math expression
    local q = math.random(1,3)..(math.random(1,2) == 1 and '+' or '*')..math.random(1,3) 
    quiz_flags[player:GetGUIDLow()] = {
      count = 1,
      question = q,
      answer = load('return '..q)() -- calculate answer
    }
    player:SendBroadcastMessage('[Notice] answer my question: '..q)
  end
end
    
RegisterPlayerEvent(32, Start)
RegisterPlayerEvent(18, ChatSystem)
```

Comment: thank you very much

Your tips helped me a lot, I solved this error